# What preferred domain should I choose for WIX website (www vs no-www)?

Tags: seo, no-www

The problem is that WIX automatically redirects all to www-domain. It is not possible to have non-www domain when using WIX.
Now, I would like my website to be distributed as non-www, but I don't know how this affects SEO if people will click on non-www links, or the will type the non-www url.
Is it ok to set in Webmaster Tools a non-www version while WIX will always redirect to www ?
Is it ok to distribute my website as non-www url?

Or I should make everything as www (i'd rather not, but if it's in my best interest, I will do that) ?

Answer (score 2):

If WIX redirects to `www` then setting the preferred domain in GWT is likely to have no effect. If the site always redirects to `www` then you have no choice but to use the `www` subdomain. The bare domain will never appear in the SERPs.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have a non-www domain with wix.  Any attempt to reach your site without "www" will result in your visitor ending up on a www-domain name.

Comment: thanks for pointing the obvious. That only makes me to think that you haven't read what I asked.

Comment: Perhaps you should write your questions more clearly. If you already know that wix will automatically redirect you then, the answer is "It doesn't matter what you do."  You will always end up with the same result".  Personally i think using wix is a bad idea.

Comment: quote from my question: "The problem is that WIX automatically redirects all to www-domain. It is not possible to have non-www domain when using WIX." - i thought is crystal-clear. And my question was about webmaster tools and seo (if is advised to use non-www as preferred domain, or I should stick to www).

Answer (score 0):

A tiny weeny amount of dissipation occurs when a page redirects from one to another, this is because 301 redirects are treated as they are links, and more so if a website [redirects outbound to another, this is near identical](http://searchengineland.com/google-pagerank-dilution-through-a-301-redirect-is-a-myth-149656). The leak obviously becomes bigger than more links you gain.

Also.... Wix not supporting non-www since when?... paying customers are allowed to use their own domain and have the option to set the IP host record in the [DNS management](https://www.wix.com/support/html5/domains/managing-your-domain-records/faq/can-i-use-cname-records-1), I see no reason why non-www wouldn't be supported nor can I find any documentation that says non-www is not supported...

Comment: I asked them how I can set a non-www domain for my website and they replied is not possible. I also found no documentation about this fact. The only "documentation" i am aware at this moment is their answer.

Comment: I'd submit another ticket. I'd say whomever you spoke to is wrong, as I'm under the impression that when you use your own domain with WIX as a paying customer you are able to setup A record.

Comment: You cannot use CNAME records for the naked domain, whether you use WIX or not. This is a design constraint of the DNS itself. This, combined with the need to do load balancing and failover, is why all domains on WIX must be redirected to www. (The IP for the naked domain is on Google Cloud Platform and Google manages its failover with route announcements. The servers which answer it only send the 301 redirect.) This is not unusual, either, nor is it the only reason why you might need to use www.

Comment: For more background on why no-www is a bad idea, you can see my web site http://www.yes-www.org/ :)